# Micronaut: How to get metrics in the Prometheus format?

Tags: metrics, prometheus, micrometer, micronaut

How should I configure the Micronaut to get the `/metrics` in the Prometheus format ?

Used: **micronaut 1.0.0.M3**

Now:

```
micronaut:
...
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
```

and result: metrics name list

```
{"names":["jvm.memory.max","executor.pool.size"...]}
```

I need to get: metrics in the prometheus format([formats](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/))

Answer (score 3):

[Micronaut Micrometer](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-micrometer/1.1.x/guide/index.html) has an [PrometheusEndpoint](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-registry-prometheus/src/main/java/io/micronaut/configuration/metrics/micrometer/prometheus/management/PrometheusEndpoint.java) from version 1.1 that will
return in Prometheus format from `/prometheus` and
can be enabled in application.yml by:

```
endpoints:
  prometheus:
    sensitive: false
```

In combination with

```
micronaut:
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
        step: PT1M
        descriptions: true
```

(The documentation is missing the endpoint config but will be [changed in the new release](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-micrometer/commit/32263928ef3414e15efbb7004237b033a7b1367d?short_path=c5f5da1#diff-c5f5da1151f2f9b7e667e96bf75f3b1d))

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, we solved the problem as follows.

1. Added a new endpoint. Or create a controller with a mapping on `/metrics`.
2. The new endpoint added a return of `scrape()`.
3. Correlated endpoint with `/prometheus` (new endpoint can not be mapped on `/metrics`).
4. Disconnected endpoint metrics which by default.

Config:

```
micronaut:   
  ...   
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true 
... 
endpoints:
...
  metrics:
    enabled: false
  prometheus:
    enabled: true
```

Comment: Hello Can you please explain how did you do it ? I didnt understood this point ? The new endpoint added a return of scrape().

Answer (score 2):

To piggyback on the other answers, here is an Micronaut endpoint that provides the Prometheus metrics in the format we needed:

```
package your.package.name

import io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry
import io.micronaut.management.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint
import io.micronaut.management.endpoint.annotation.Read

@Endpoint(id = "prometheus", value = "/prometheus", defaultEnabled = true, 
defaultSensitive = false)
class PrometheusController(val prometheusMeterRegistry: PrometheusMeterRegistry) {
    @Read
    fun scrape(): String {
        return prometheusMeterRegistry.scrape()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this out but based on the following:

https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/master/configurations/micrometer-registry-prometheus/src/main/java/io/micronaut/configuration/metrics/micrometer/prometheus/PrometheusMeterRegistryFactory.java

Your yaml should look like

```
metrics:
  prometheus:
    enabled: true
```

don't believe the export comes into play.

Comment: This does not work.
PrometheusMeterRegistry simply collects metrics. It has the method scrape(). This method returns the required format. But this method is not involved anywhere.