# How to change the path of an endpoint in Micronaut?

Tags: prometheus, metrics, micronaut, micrometer

I have set up micronaut using the cli and want to add an endpoint that provides prometheus metrics. Following the guides (and [Micronaut: How to get metrics in the Prometheus format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892700/micronaut-how-to-get-metrics-in-the-prometheus-format)), I added things to my `application.yml` the following  way:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: foo-service
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
        step: PT1M
        descriptions: true
endpoints:
  metrics:
    enabled: true
  prometheus:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
```

Now I have two endpoints, one at `/metrics` and one at `/prometheus`. However, I want `/metrics` to return prometheus metrics. Any idea how I can achieve that?

I know I could go and put all endpoints under a sub-path, such as `/endpoints` using `endpoints.all.path` and then proxy to there, but that really is ugly and not that way I want to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to james-kleeth I got to the right track, although it basically is a re-implementation. I disabled the prometheus endpoint and added a controller. However, when the endpoint is disabled I cannot inject it anymore. Its implementation was "trivial" (just referencing to the prometheus registry). This is my solution:

```
package my.company.service

import io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry
import io.micronaut.configuration.metrics.annotation.RequiresMetrics
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation
import javax.inject.Inject

@RequiresMetrics
@Controller("/metrics")
class MetricsController @Inject constructor(val prometheusMeterRegistry: PrometheusMeterRegistry) {
    @Operation(summary = "Provide metrics in Prometheus format")
    @Get
    @Produces("text/plain; version=0.0.4")
    fun metrics(): String = prometheusMeterRegistry.scrape()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The example given by lena_punkt works for me.
I will just add a Java example and some confs which were necessary for me in my application.yml.

```
endpoints:
  metrics:
    enabled: false
    sensitive: false
  prometheus:
    enabled: false
    sensitive: false
```

```java
import io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry;
import io.micronaut.configuration.metrics.annotation.RequiresMetrics;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@RequiresMetrics
@Controller("/metrics")
public class PrometheusController {

    private final PrometheusMeterRegistry prometheusMeterRegistry;

    @Inject
    public PrometheusController(PrometheusMeterRegistry prometheusMeterRegistry) {
        this.prometheusMeterRegistry = prometheusMeterRegistry;
    }

    @Get
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String metrics() {
        return prometheusMeterRegistry.scrape();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the metrics endpoint and create a controller that responds to `/metrics`. That controller could inject the `PrometheusEndpoint` and delegate the call the to the endpoint bean.

Comment: That only works partially. I can add a controller that binds to `/metrics` and inject the `PrometheusEndpoint`. But that one is only available as a bean when it is enabled in `application.yml`, which makes it available at `/prometheus`. So now I have it available on two paths.
Any chance to not have it bind to `/prometheus`?